# mapPartitions returns empty array

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have the following RDD which has 4 partitions:-

```
val rdd=sc.parallelize(1 to 20,4)
```

Now I try to call mapPartitions on this:-

```
scala> rdd.mapPartitions(x=> { println(x.size); x }).collect
5
5
5
5
res98: Array[Int] = Array()
```

Why does it return empty array? The anonymoys function is simply returning the same iterator it received, then how is it returning empty array? The interesting part is that if I remove println statement, it indeed returns non empty array:-

```
scala> rdd.mapPartitions(x=> { x }).collect
res101: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
```

This I don't understand. How come the presence of println (which is simply printing size of iterator) affecting the final outcome of the function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because `x` is a `TraversableOnce`, which means that you traversed it by calling `size` and then returned it back....empty.

You could work around it a number of ways, but here is one:

```
rdd.mapPartitions(x=> {
  val list = x.toList;
  println(list.size);
  list.toIterator
}).collect
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is going on we have to take a look at the signature of the function you pass to `mapPartitions`:

```
(Iterator[T]) ⇒ Iterator[U]
```

So what is an `Iterator`? If you take a look at the [`Iterator` documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator) you'll see it is a trait which extends `TraversableOnce`:

```
trait Iterator[+A] extends TraversableOnce[A]
```

Above should give you a hint what happens in your case. Iterators provide two methods `hasNext` and `next`. To get the `size` of the Iterator you have to simply iterate over it. After that `hasNext` returns `false` and you get an empty `Iterator` as the result.