# Empty array returned by mapPartitions in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, partition

hello could someone explain to me why `mapPartitions` reacts differently to those two functions? (I have looked at this [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042151/mappartitions-returns-empty-array) and I don't think my problem comes from the fact that my iterable is `TraversableOnce` as I create it.

```
L=range(10)
J=range(5,15)
K=range(8,18)

data=J+K+L

def function_1(iter_listoflist):
    final_iterator=[]
    for sublist in iter_listoflist:
        final_iterator.append([x for x in sublist if x%9!=0])
    return iter(final_iterator)  

def function_2(iter_listoflist):
    final_iterator=[]
    listoflist=list(iter_listoflist)
    for i in range(len(listoflist)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(listoflist)):
            sublist=listoflist[i]+listoflist[j]
            final_iterator.append([x for x in sublist if x%9!=0])
            pass
        pass
    return iter(final_iterator)



sc.parallelize(data,3).glom().mapPartitions(function_1).collect()
```

returns what it should while

```
sc.parallelize(data,3).glom().mapPartitions(function_2).collect()
```

returns an empty array, I have the checked the code by returning a list at the end and it does what I want it to.

thanks for your help

Philippe C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually quite simple. `listoflist` has always length equal to 1. To understand why that is the case you have to think about what is going on when call `glom`. To quote [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.glom) it returns:

> an RDD created by coalescing all elements within each partition
>   into a list.

It means that when you call:

```
listoflist=list(iter_listoflist)
```

You get a list with a single element list containing all elements from that partition. Ignoring all the details:

```
(sc.parallelize(data, 3)
    .glom()
    .mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda i, iter: [(i, list(iter))])
    .collect())

## [(0, [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]),
##     (1, [[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]]),
##     (2, [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])]
```

It means that

- `range(len(listoflist))` contains a single element equal 0.
- `range(i+1,len(listoflist))` by substitution is an empty `range(1, 1)`

Hence there is nothing to do and you get an empty iterator.

On a side note all these `pass` statements as well as `iter` calls are completely obsolete.

Comment: thank you for your answer and side note I'll take it into account. Is it of length 1 because it is called by mapPartition? When I did my tests it was of length the size of my list or iterator.

Comment: No, it because you're using `glom`

Comment: Ok thank you very much, my work arround was to do the two for loops somewhere else and then call parallelize and it worked. If I don't use glom() I have an error message as I try to iterate on ints. is there a way to have the loop inside the function? I am basically trying to compute the lists in parallel but need that they don't mix. thanks again

Comment: Could you ask this a separate question and try to explain exactly what is the logic here? I have this strange feeling that code you've provided doesn't really reflect the expected output.

Comment: sure here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562318/how-to-specify-the-partition-for-mappartition-in-spark